# Android Devices not connecting to php server

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-volley

I am trying to connect to my phpmyadmin server using volley, i managed to access my sql database and send/receive data from the server using the emulator: yet this somehow doesnt seem to work on android devices (tried multiple ones)

Any idea on how to solve this? 
*Code attached below

```
package com.example.databasehelper452;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main22Activity extends AppCompatActivity {


    TextView textViewdisplaydata;
    com.android.volley.RequestQueue requestQueue;
   // String insertUrl = "http://192.168.16.4:80/DevicesServer/insertEntry.php";  //in order to contain the url for our php files
  //  String showUrl = "http://192.168.16.4:80/DevicesServer/displayEntry.php";

    String insertUrl = "http://10.168.46.13:80/DevicesServer/insertEntry.php";
    String showUrl = "http://10.168.46.13:80/DevicesServer/displayEntry.php";

    EditText plaintxtmacmaster,plaintxtmacconnected;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main22);

        plaintxtmacconnected = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.plaintxtmacconnected);
        plaintxtmacmaster = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.plaintxtmacmaster);


        textViewdisplaydata =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewdisplaydata);



        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    }
    String Result = "";

    public void onbtnclickshowall(View view) {
        Result = "";
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, showUrl, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
        {
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
            {
                try {
                    JSONArray posts = response.getJSONArray("devices");
                    for (int i = 0; i < posts.length();i++) {

                        JSONObject post = posts.getJSONObject(i);

                        String MACConnected = post.getString("MACConnected");
                        String MACMasterDevice = post.getString("MACMasterDevice");
                        String DeviceName = post.getString("DeviceName");
                        String DateLastDetection = post.getString("DateLastDetection");
                        String FrequencyDetection = post.getString("FrequencyDetection");
                        String CumulativeDetection = post.getString("CumulativeDetection");
                        String MasterName = post.getString("MasterName");


                        Result = Result + "\n"+ MACConnected+ " " + DeviceName + " " + DateLastDetection+" "+FrequencyDetection+" "+ CumulativeDetection+" " + MACMasterDevice+" "+MasterName+" ";
                        String result2 = Result;
                        textViewdisplaydata.setText(Result);

                    }

                }
                catch (JSONException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener()
        {
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
            {

            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

    }

    public void onbtnclickinsertall(View view) {


            StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, insertUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    System.out.println(response.toString());
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }) {

                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String,String> parameters  = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    parameters.put("MACConnected",plaintxtmacconnected.getText().toString());
                    parameters.put("MACMasterDevice",plaintxtmacmaster.getText().toString());
                    parameters.put("DeviceName","JAD");
                    parameters.put("DateLastDetection","1234567");
                    parameters.put("FrequencyDetection","12");
                    parameters.put("CumulativeDetection","12345");
                    parameters.put("MasterName","Master Test");






                    return parameters;
                }
            };
            requestQueue.add(request);
        }





}



    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.databasehelper452">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Main22Activity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Make sure your devices are connected to the same network. Secondly grant privileges on php project to access data.
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/c63ec5/mysql-create-user-and-grant-privileges-for-php-code/

Comment: Here, you need a static IP or a domain  which contents your php codes and than provide that path here,  String insertUrl = "http://10.168.46.13:80/DevicesServer/insertEntry.php";
    String showUrl = "http://10.168.46.13:80/DevicesServer/displayEntry.php";

Comment: `trying to connect to my phpmyadmin server`. Dont think so. You probably want to make contact with a php script on your webserver. You posted much to much code. Please post only relevant code. And if the code does not work then tell how it flows and which errors or exceptions there are.

Comment: Where is your server residing? On the internet or in LAN?

Comment: The server is on my local host: all devices are connected through the same LAN @greenapps

Comment: @SarvagnaMehta This is the IP of my LAN, since phpmyadmin is localhost on my laptop: I made sure to get exact IP for my router. 
Please note that it worked just fine on the emulator

Comment: `tell how it flows and which errors or exceptions there are.`. Any reason not to tell us?

Comment: `This is the IP of my LAN`. That is nonsense. Every device in your LAN has a different ip. `exact IP for my router` ???? You clients need to use the ip of your laptop.

Comment: @greenapps sorry for the long code, I thought that posting all details would help figuring out any missing steps for the android devices: 
The emulator is working just fine to connect via php scripts to mysql: all what im missing is the actual devices accessing the scripts

Comment: @greenapps not reluctant: tried to solve this on android device, I didnt work: yet on emulator it does: so Im missing something in the code for devices: any clue about that? the code works: im positive about it -